# How to create a chart that uses strings for both the X and Y axes?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

On the documentation page of ChartJS, there is exactly a section corresponding to my question, but I cannot understand its [instruction](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/category.html). It writes:

> If global configuration is used, labels are drawn from one of the
>   label arrays included in the chart data. If only data.labels is
>   defined, this will be used. If data.xLabels is defined and the axis is
>   horizontal, this will be used. Similarly, if data.yLabels is defined
>   and the axis is vertical, this property will be used. Using both
>   xLabels and yLabels together can create a chart that uses strings for
>   both the X and Y axes.
>
> Specifying any of the settings above defines the x axis as type:
>   category if not defined otherwise. For more fine-grained control of
>   category labels it is also possible to add labels as part of the
>   category axis definition. Doing so does not apply the global defaults.

Here is what I have tried:

```js
var options = {
    type: "line",
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            label: "My First Dataset",
            data: [{
                x: 'January',
                y: 'A'
            }, {
                x: 'March',
                y: 'B'
            }],
            fill: false,
            borderColor: "rgb(75, 192, 192)",
            lineTension: 0.1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'category',
                labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June'],
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                type: 'category',
                labels: ["A", "B", "C"],
            }]
        }
    }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
    <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

And also this:

```js
var options = {
    type: "line",
    data: {
        xLabels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June"],
        yLabels: ["A", "B", "C"],
        datasets: [{
            label: "My First Dataset",
            data: [{
                x: 'January',
                y: 'A'
            }, {
                x: 'March',
                y: 'B'
            }],
            fill: false,
            borderColor: "rgb(75, 192, 192)",
            lineTension: 0.1
        }]
    },
    options: {}
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
    <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

Unfortunately none of these are working.

Comment: In a line chart, the y-axis values are numbers because the *values* are expected to be numbers. You can use a yAxis "ticks" callback to map the number values to some strings. Chart will pass the callback the number it wants to use as a y axis increment label, and you can map that to whatever string you want.

Comment: A=1; B=2; C=3 .. .. ..

Comment: @Pointy I have tried to change the strings into numbers but it is still not working. Would you mind amending my code and show me a working example? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I got the solution after many trial-and-errors. I have to say that the documentation of `chart.js` is quite unclear and should be improved.

My findings are:

- `xLabels` and `yLabels` approach is not working. There are no clear documentation on these two parameters.
- Don't care about setting the `type` to `category`. `chart.js` only accepts numerical values; you have to map the values to strings by using your own callback method.

```js
var options = {
    type: "line",
    data: {
        labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June'],
        datasets: [{
            label: "My First Dataset",
            data: [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1],
            fill: false,
            borderColor: "rgb(75, 192, 192)",
            lineTension: 0.1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    max: 3,
                    min: 1,
                    stepSize: 1,
                    callback: function(label, index, labels) {
                        switch (label) {
                            case 1:
                                return 'A';
                            case 2:
                                return 'B';
                            case 3:
                                return 'C';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
    <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, this is right, and I also agree that the documentation is lacking in clarity. It's not that it's *bad*, but there's a paucity of explanatory "concept" material.